# 404 page not found..The page you requested was not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have downloaded a codeigniter 2.1.3.. when a run it from localhost like this localhost/codeigniter
it gives me an error
404 page not found..The page you requested was not found.
i dont know what to do as i am a new to codeignitor framework ..

Comment: Did you read user guide? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html

Comment: what is name of your folder of codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

change the folder name as per you want, put this folder in document root(if it is not there already) and access it like

```
http://localhost/foldername/
```

this will open codeigniter's default controller and method which will show you a start page

default url format for accessing the controller method is

```
http://localhost/foldername/index.php/ControllName/MethodName
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you will need to setup mod_rewrite on your apache. Most frameworks use .htaccess with mod_rewrite configuration inside. More about [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). If you use linux os you can execute next command to enable mod_rewrite on apache.

```
a2enmod rewrite
```